# Xamarin iOS text binding issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Does anyone know this issue only happens on iOS devices, what I've concluded at the moment is that if i use `Text="Binding <variable>` it doesn't work, else it works fine.

error first occurs when i scroll up and down the view.

[Code](https://pastebin.com/dET5nHCS) (tried to insert the code with the code tags but got error for formatting)
[image]
[image]

Currently using:

1. XF.Material 1.6.5 -> 1.5.8
2. Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.1080 -> 4.6.0.847
3. Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.3.2
4. NETStandard.Library 2.0.3

Edit: added more code since it might be the `material:MaterialCard` which creates the problem, also added nuget package versions
Edit: Fixed by rolling back libraries

Comment: Is there any purpose for x:name="test" and x:name="testtest" ?

Comment: no it was just an attempt to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by rolling back libaries see post for what got rolled back